Dependency 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.6.0.Beta2' not found
I have added the mapstruct dependency:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0.Beta2</version>
</dependency>

but the artifact and the version are marked in red:

As a next step, I have added the respective plugin:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
   <configuration>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
        <path>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0.Beta2</version>
        </path>
    </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

The problem is that when I include @Mapper in my code, it gives me the following error:

Cannot resolve symbol 'Mapper'


Wich spring version are you currently using? Are you using lombok?
